# Preventing the creation of a specific directory

Tags: linux, permissions, directory

I'd like to cover the bases on a vulnerability which tries to download itself and save the result in a newly created directory inside the `/tmp/` directory.

To be on the safe side, I wish to make it impossible to create folders inside `/tmp/`.  Or if that is not feasible, I would like to prevent creating folders in just one specific directory inside `/tmp`.

Comment: The phrase is `cover the bases`, probably from baseball.  http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/cover+all+the+bases

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use `ls -l -d /tmp/` and you will see that the permissions are set to `drwxrwxrwt`, i.e. `d`: a directory, `rwx`: read, write and execute permissions allowed for owner, group and others (in this order), `t` sticky bit, i.e. only file owners are allowed to delete files (not the group despite permissions). Let's leave the sticky bit aside for the moment and mention that a directory needs to be executable for being accessible.

Now if you want to restrict write permission for others (owner and group is root) then use `chmod o-w /tmp/` (as root, i.e. using `sudo` )

HOWEVER: `/tmp/` is rather important for may processes that need temporary data, so I would suggest not to restrict permissions for this folder at all!

Since you are heading for a specific folder the simplest would be to manually create that folder (as root) and then restrict permission for it:

```
sudo mkdir /tmp/badfolder
sudo chmod -R o-w /tmp/badfolder/
```

Side note on chmod: `-R` do recursively, u,g,o: user,group,other , +- add/remove permission to r,w,x read,write,execute. I.e. for allowing gorup members to write to a file, use `chmod g+w file`.

---

Update:

In case the process is running as root, you also need to set the 'i' attribute. From `man chattr`

> A file with the `i' attribute cannot be modified: it cannot be deleted or renamed, no link can be created to this  file  and  no  data  can  be  written  to  the  file.   Only  the  superuser  or  a  process  possessing  the
>          CAP_LINUX_IMMUTABLE capability can set or clear this attribute.

This would also apply if the folder was not owned by root. Simply use

```
chattr +i /tmp/badfolder
```

Use `chattr -i /tmp/badfolder` for removing it and `-R` for doing either recursively.

Comment: ... Unless the installer runs as root. Maybe add chattr?

Comment: very good point, I updated the answer.

Comment: @Fiximan I already upvoted :p... I knew of the chmod command, but the chattr +i... (Glad I asked the question!)

Comment: You could also just make it a symlink to itself.  `ln -s foo /tmp`.  `touch /tmp/foo/bar:  ... Too many levels of symbolic links`.  A rootkit is much less likely to try `chattr` than `rm -rf /tmp/foo` before creating its dir, though.

Comment: @JeffSchaller: `chmod 000` would block any process that didn't `rmdir` it.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively to Fixman's idea, you could also just make it a symlink to itself.

```
sudo ln -s foo /tmp

$ touch /tmp/foo/bar
touch: cannot touch ‘/tmp/foo/bar’: Too many levels of symbolic links

#Or
sudo mkdir -m 000 /tmp/foo  # create with mode 000, no permissions at all.
```

Creating them as root will block non-root malware from removing / renaming them.

Mode 444 (read, but not write or execute) will prevent software from complaining that it can't list the directory, if you `ls -R /tmp` or equivalent.

A rootkit is much less likely to try `chattr` than `rm -rf /tmp/foo` before creating its dir, though.

Comment: are you sure about mode 444? shouldn't it rather be 555 for allowing to `cd` into the dir?

Comment: @Fiximan: I intentionally excluded that.  `du`, `find`, etc., won't give errors, because they won't read any contents that they want to access inside the dir.  Otherwise I'd make it `000`.